TailwindCSS Styles Not Persisting with react.tsx weird isssue
Whenever I go to my app.blade.php file and add the bg-red-800 class to the  tag and then remove it, my Tailwind styles start working on my React .tsx components. However, when I refresh the page, the Tailwind styles stop working again, and I have to repeat the process. This issue affects all Tailwind styling. Could someone help me?
UPDATE: it only happens when i do a hard refresh.
Check the image for more information.
image1: Tailwind styles are not working as expected
image2: The second image I added the bg-red-800 class in app.blade.php
image3: After removing bg-red-800, the Tailwind styles start working in adminHeader.tsx
[


tailwind.config.js
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import forms from '@tailwindcss/forms';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/**/*.tsx',
        './resources/js/**/*.jsx',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            screens: {
                '3xl': '1920px',
                '4xl': '2560px',
            },
            maxWidth: {
                'screen-3xl': '1920px',
                'screen-4xl': '2560px',
            },
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [
        forms,
    ],
};

app.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

app.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'LogiLearn') }}</title>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Scripts -->
        @routes
        @viteReactRefresh
        @vite(['resources/js/app.tsx', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.tsx"])
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', now()])
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>

app.tsx
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

import ns1 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/nl.json";
import ns2 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/tr.json";
import ns3 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/de.json";
import ns4 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/dk.json";
import ns5 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/pl.json";
import ns6 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/fr.json"
import ns7 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/en.json";
import ns8 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/bg.json";
import ns9 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/ro.json";
import ns10 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/es.json";
import ns11 from "../../../../LogiLearn/LogiLearn/resources/js/ts/lang/hu.json";

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.tsx`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.tsx')),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        const root = createRoot(el);

        root.render(<App {...props} />);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});

i18n
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        resources: {
            nl: {
                translation: ns1,
            },
            tr: {
                translation: ns2,
            },
            de: {
                translation: ns3,
            },
            dk: {
                translation: ns4,
            },
            pl: {
                translation: ns5,
            },
            fr: {
                translation: ns6,
            },
            en: {
                translation: ns7,
            },
            bg: {
                translation: ns8,
            },
            ro: {
                translation: ns9,
            },
            es: {
                translation: ns10,
            },
            hu: {
                translation: ns11,
            },
        },
        lng: "nl",
        ns: ["translation"],
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        detection: {
            order: ['localStorage', 'navigator'],
            caches: ['localStorage'],
        },
    });

export default i18n;

adminheader.tsx
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {useTranslation} from "react-i18next";
import {Link} from "@inertiajs/react";
import UserIconWhite from "../../ui/icons/UserIconWhite";

const AdminHeader: React.FC = () => {
    const {t} = useTranslation();

    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleDropDown = () => {
        setOpen(!isOpen);
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex w-full bg-red-800">
            <p>{t('managerAdmin.managerAdminHeader.courses')}</p>
            <p>Planning</p>
            <Link href={route('employees')}>{t('managerAdmin.managerAdminHeader.myEmployee')}</Link>
            <p>Signalen</p>

            <div
                className="size-16 flex items-center justify-center customGreen">
                <button onClick={handleDropDown}>
                    <UserIconWhite/>
                </button>
                {/*<div*/}
                {/*    id="dropdown"*/}
                {/*    className={`z-10 w-44 bg-white rounded divide-y divide-gray-100 shadow ${*/}
                {/*        isOpen ? "block" : "hidden"*/}
                {/*    }`}*/}
                {/*>*/}
                {/*    <ul className="z-10 w-44 bg-white rounded divide-y divide-gray-100 shadow">*/}
                {/*        <li>*/}
                {/*            <Link href={route('profile')}>*/}
                {/*                {t('managerAdmin.managerAdminHeader.myProfile')}*/}
                {/*            </Link>*/}
                {/*        </li>*/}
                {/*    </ul>*/}
                {/*</div>*/}
            </div>


        </div>
    );
}

export default AdminHeader;

